# VBA Text Array - Scan two columns rather than one

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have some code which is designed to scan columns `F` and `G` for occurrences of words found in an array, the array containing text found in column `J`.

Column `J` contains free text from a field in SAP. Being free text, it could be "Kerry John Pub Expenses" or "CATS O/H Kerry John", or even "CATS John Kerry O/H". There is no data entry standard for this field... and this is what makes this task difficult.

**Example**

Here we have 4 rows of data, "John Citizen" is located in row `3`, therefore the blank cells in columns `F` and `G`, row 2 can be populated with his first and last name.

[image]

[image]

I would like some suggestions as to how this code could be re-written to achieve this result more efficiently

```
    Sub arraycolumnmatch()
    Dim txtArray As Variant, T As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

    For I = 2 To Range("E50000").End(xlUp).row
        typ = Range("F" & I).Value
    If typ = "" Then
        txt = Range("J" & I).Value
        txtArray = Split(txt, " ")

        For Each T In txtArray
            For J = 2 To Range("G50000").End(xlUp).row
                If Range("G" & J).Value = T Then
                    match_txt = T
                    Range("G" & I).Value = match_txt
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next J
        Next T

        For Each T In txtArray
            For J = 2 To Range("F50000").End(xlUp).row
                If Range("F" & J).Value = T Then
                       match_txt = T

                 'Check for surnames which could match first names such as Mary Michael
                       If Not Range("G" & I).Value = T Then

                          Range("F" & I).Value = match_txt
                          Exit For
                       End If
                End If
            Next J
        Next T
   End If
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the code does what you want it to be doing, only too slow... right?

Comment: It is slow, but there is also another problem.  Column J contains free text from a field in SAP, Column F and Column G contains first names  and last names.  The code makes an assumption, if it finds an entry in column F or G that matches an entry in the txt array, it will copy and paste that entry.  My issue is that if it does it one at a time, it makes mistakes with names like Tony Andrew or Phillip Mary due to the fact that they are common first names

Comment: You'll probably want to ask on Stack Overflow and get the code to work as intended first, *then* post the working code here to get it peer reviewed - until your code works as it should, it's not ready for Code Review :(

Comment: I have updated it, it now functions correctly and solves my problem, but would like a review and see if it can be written to operate more efficiently.

Answer (score 8):

## Consistent Indentation.

The first thing I would address, is the indentation. Improving code that isn't properly formatted is just... not right.

Here are the signs:

```
Sub arraycolumnmatch()
Dim txtArray As Variant, T As Variant
Dim I As Long, J As Long
```

And:

```
Next I
End Sub
```

But also:

```
 'Check for surnames which could match first names such as Mary Michael
       If Not Range("G" & I).Value = T Then
```

The key is *consistency* - here's your code, with *consistent* indentation (comments omitted). Notice each code block (`If...End If`, `For...Next`, etc.) consistently adds an indentation level, and the end of the block lines up with its beginning - also notice that indentation levels are consistently 4 spaces wide; that's the default VBE setting for the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key:

```
Sub arraycolumnmatch()
|
|   Dim txtArray As Variant, T As Variant
|   Dim I As Long, J As Long
|
|   For I = 2 To Range("E50000").End(xlUp).row
|   |   typ = Range("F" & I).Value
|   |   If typ = "" Then
|   |   |   txt = Range("J" & I).Value
|   |   |   txtArray = Split(txt, " ")
|   |   |
|   |   |   For Each T In txtArray
|   |   |   |   For J = 2 To Range("G50000").End(xlUp).row
|   |   |   |   |   If Range("G" & J).Value = T Then
|   |   |   |   |   |   match_txt = T
|   |   |   |   |   |   Range("G" & I).Value = match_txt
|   |   |   |   |   |   Exit For
|   |   |   |   |   End If
|   |   |   |   Next J
|   |   |   Next T
|   |   |
|   |   |   For Each T In txtArray
|   |   |   |   For J = 2 To Range("F50000").End(xlUp).row
|   |   |   |   |   If Range("F" & J).Value = T Then
|   |   |   |   |   |   match_txt = T
|   |   |   |   |   |   If Not Range("G" & I).Value = T Then
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   Range("F" & I).Value = match_txt
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   Exit For
|   |   |   |   |   |   End If
|   |   |   |   |   End If
|   |   |   |   Next J
|   |   |   Next T
|   |   End If
|   Next I
|
End Sub
```

Much easier to follow, isn't it?

---

## Meaningful Names.

Next thing I would address is the naming. Improving code where you have to quadruple-check every change you make because you're not sure you're changing the right thing is just not efficient. Using meaningful names for all identifiers fixes that.

Starting with the method's name itself:

```
Sub arraycolumnmatch()
```

Typically, VBA (VB in general) method names are `PascalCase`, for better readability. That would make it `ArrayColumnMatch` - but good method/procedure names should also start with a verb. *What's this method doing exactly?* should be answerable by simply looking at it's name.

The problem is, the method in question *is doing too many things*, so giving it a meaningful name is hard. But I'll get back to that.

Avoid chopping off identifers, like `typ` when you meant `type` - but then `Type` is a reserved keyword.. the solution isn't to make it *less* readable! I'm not sure which worksheet `Range` is referring to because `Range` is an implicit reference to `Application.ActiveSheet` (and that's **very** bug-prone!), so I'll just assume you meant to call it `documentType`.

`txt` is another meaningless name (heck, people use that as a *prefix* for `TextBox` controls!): it stands for that manual entry field you're trying to parse, right? How about `targetFieldValue`, or `manualTextField`?

Also avoid single-letter identifiers, like `T` - assuming `txt` is `manualTextField`, I'd go with `manualTextFieldValue`.

Local variables are typically named in `camelCase`, so `I` and `J` would be `i` and `j` - those are typically used for iterating loops as you're doing, so I'm not going to complain about those, except both loops seem to be iterating the very same rows on the active sheet (whatever that is), and they're nested, too... and since they're row numbers I'd typically name them `xlRow[WhatItsFor]`.

---

## Undeclared Identifiers

Always, systematically, consistently, automatically, thoughtlessly stick `Option Explicit` at the top of every VBA module. Don't question it, just do it: without it, you can have a bug by simply having a little typo in an identifier name. With it, your VBA code will refuse to compile and run if an identifier isn't declared anywhere. Use it. Always.

If `match_txt` is declared outside the scope of the procedure, then move the declaration inside that scope - it doesn't need to be at module scope. Always declare variables at the smallest possible scope; globals are evil.

---

## vbNullString

A very minor point, but I have to mention it.

```
If typ = "" Then
```

Avoid using an *empty string* `""` to mean *no value*. VBA defines the constant `vbNullString` specifically for that. And why should you bother typing `vbNullString` when `""` does the same thing?

That's the thing. *It doesn't do the same thing*. `""` is a full-fledged `String` value that needs its own allocated memory space. `vbNullString` is a null string pointer that's not allocated anywhere. Of course it's a very minor performance hit to allocate that string, but semantically, `vbNullString` is the right thing to do.

Don't believe me? Try this in the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G):

```
?"Address for empty string: " & StrPtr("") & vbNewLine & "Address for vbNullString: " & StrPtr(vbNullString)
```

I get this output:

```
Address for empty string: 241665720
Address for vbNullString: 0
```

There's some kind of optimization going on under the hood though, so the pointer for `""` will be reused every time it's encountered in your application's lifetime - as I said it's a very minor point. But just as you wouldn't declare an unused variable, you shouldn't allocate a memory address for a built-in constant value.

---

## Twin Loops

You have this:

```
For Each T In txtArray
```

And then a few lines further, you have that:

```
For Each T In txtArray
```

You're iterating all elements of `txtArray` twice, when once would suffice. Also, wouldn't the last row of column "G" be the same last row as in column "F"? Wouldn't that last row be the same for every iteration of `T`? I'm asking, because your data *seems* to be laid out in a *table* with *records*, so you'd only need to find the row for the *last record*, whichever column you're using for that is irrelevant, no?

```
For J = 2 To Range("G50000").End(xlUp).row
...
For J = 2 To Range("F50000").End(xlUp).row
```

I'd extract a variable here, and assign it to `Range("G50000").End(xlUp).row` *before* the `For Each T In txtArray` loop starts, and then do

```
For J = 2 To xlLastRow
```

Then you're writing to `G[i]` if the value of `G[j]` matches the current `txtArray` element, and to `F[i]` if `G[i]` wasn't written to and the value of `F[j]` matches the current `txtArray` element.

Wouldn't that do the same thing then?

```
If Range("G" & j).Value = T Then
    Range("G" & i).Value = T
Else If Range("F" & j).Value = T Then
    Range("F" & i).Value = T
End If
```

Lastly, the `J` loop looks like it could be implemented as a `Find` instead of a loop.

---

## Extract Methods.

> *The problem is, the method in question **is doing too many things**, so giving it a meaningful name is hard. But I'll get back to that.*

So here we are. What's that method doing actually?

It...

- finds the row number for the last record on the active sheet
- iterates all records on the active sheet
- splits a value in the current record into an array of values
- iterates all values in that array
- looks for a match of that value somewhere in columns G and F
- writes that value to column G or F, whichever comes first

Extracting methods is a *refactoring* operation, and doing that manually in VBA is, honestly, a pain in the neck.

I've authored a refactoring tool that does exactly that (and more):

[image: Rubberduck's Extract Method refactoring]

Of course I have a little bit of a vested interest (very little - it's free and open-source actually), but I'd recommend you take a look at what the [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduck-vba.com/) VBE add-in can do for you.

Answer (score 4):

### Speed it up #1: Minimize sheet access

Besides what @Mat'sMug said, there are a few other ways to speed things up.

In my experience, reading Excel cells from VBA is slow. You're iterating over a range several times. It probably would be faster to read those ranges into a VBA array and then loop over that instead:

```
Dim ColumnF As Variant, ColumnG As Variant

ColumnF = Range("F2:F" & xlLastRow).Value2
ColumnG = Range("G2:G" & xlLastRow).Value2

' or even

Dim ColumnF() As String, ColumnG() As String
ReDim ColumnF(xlLastRow)
Redim ColumnG(xlLastRow)
' and then fill each in once with a For/Next
' then refer to ColumnF() or ColumnG() instead of Range("F"&...)
```

### Speed it up #2: Use the right data structure for the job

This is a key principle of software development. When you're repeatedly searching a set of items for a string, you don't want to store that list in an array (or an array-like structure like Excel cells) -- you want to store it in a hash table or dictionary. VBA didn't originally come with a `Dictionary`, but Microsoft added one after the fact as part of the Microsoft Scripting Library. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187234

You'll need to add a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".

So, instead of loading into an array at startup, load column G and column F into `Dictionary`s. I also suggest using meaningful names.

```
Dim firstNames As Dictionary
Dim lastNames As Dictionary

For J = 2 To xlLastRow
    firstNames.Add Key := Range("F" & j), 1
    lastNames.Add Key := Range("G" & j), 1
Next J
```

Now you can check whether an entry is in each `Dictionary` in a flash:

```
    Dim lnf as Boolean, fnf as Boolean
    lnf = False
    fnf = False
    For Each T In txtArray
        If Not lnf Then
            If lastNames.Exists(T) Then
                 match_txt = T
                 Range("G" & I).Value = match_txt
                 If fnf Then Exit For
                 lnf = True
            End If
        End If
        If Not fnf Then
            If firstNames.Exists(T) Then
                 match_txt = T
                 Range("F" & I).Value = match_txt
                 if lnf Then Exit For
                 fnf = True
            End If
        End If
    Next T
```

Also for reference:

- https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/comparing-two-lists-vba-udf-shootout-between-linear-search-binary-search-collection-and-dictionary/
- http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html
- https://newtonexcelbach.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/arrays-vs-collections-vs-dictionary-objects-and-dictionary-help/